# Magento 2 grid issue when clicking a row: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined

Tags: magento2, javascript, grid

i have a grid in which i display data from a DataProvider. The issue is when i click on a row, it returns the following javascript issue:

```
actions.js:216 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined
    at UiClass._getCallback (actions.js:216)
    at UiClass.applyAction (actions.js:156)
    at registry.js:59
    at Registry._resolveRequest (registry.js:418)
    at Registry._addRequest (registry.js:385)
    at Registry.get (registry.js:229)
    at async (registry.js:58)
    at column.js:291
    at UiClass.applySingleAction (column.js:253)
    at UiClass.applyFieldAction (column.js:228)
```

I assume something's wrong with either the configuration of the grid, of the columns or the actionsColumn.

The code for my grid is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">my_grid.my_grid_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">my_grid.my_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">my_columns</item>
    </argument>

...

    <columns name="my_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">my_grid.my_grid.my_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>

...

        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Company\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\MyActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">100</item>
                    <item name="viewUrlPath" xsi:type="string">*/*/edit</item>
                    <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

and in MyActions class i have the following:

```
...
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            $name = $this->getData('name');
            if (isset($item['id'])) {
                
                $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                        self::MY_URL_PATH_EDIT,
                        [
                            'id' => $item['id']
                        ]
                    ),
                    'label' => __('Edit')
                ];

            }
        }
    }
}
                
...
```

Any idea what am i missing?

Comment: What is name of primary key in DB?

Comment: Hello @Ankit, the primary key field is "id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out, i had two issues:

**1)** i needed to add a column with the "id" field in the grid. (my primary key from the database table).
That is because i was using that key in my MyActions.prepareDataSource() function.

```
$item[$name]['edit'] = [
    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
        self::MY_URL_PATH_EDIT,
        [
            'id' => $item['id']
        ]
    ,
    'label' => __('Edit')
];
```

**2)** in the "<settings>" section of the columns, i had to write "edit" instead of "view" to match the action from the MyActions.prepareDataSource() which was "edit":

XML:

```
<item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
```

PHP:

```
 $item[$name]['edit'] = [ ... ]
```

After this, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `indexField` in your XML, this field helps initialize the `actions` array. I suggest you copy from Magento's core modules (any) and modify it instead of writing your own.

Link example to cms module: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/81672a278634e59965d2694e8f9107abf104ab14/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_listing.xml#L188

Comment: Hello Jimmy, i actually do have the indexField, it's
*<item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>*

Comment: My bad. Everything looks ok to me. For situation like this, I always debug the JS to check why the error happen.